# « …et le hasard n'est à personne » (La Peste, Albert Camus)

Tags: sens, verbes, formulation-idiomatique

> C’est ainsi que ces hommes en vinrent à négliger de plus en plus souvent les
> règles d’hygiène qu’ils avaient codifiées, à oublier
> quelques-unes des nombreuses désinfections qu’ils
> devaient pratiquer sur eux-mêmes, à courir quelquefois,
> sans être prémunis contre la contagion, auprès des
> malades atteints de peste pulmonaire, parce que,
> prévenus au dernier moment qu’il fallait se rendre dans
> les maisons infectées, il leur avait paru d’avance épuisant
> de retourner dans quelque local pour se faire les
> instillations nécessaires. Là était le vrai danger, car c’était
> la lutte elle-même contre la peste qui les rendait alors le
> plus vulnérables à la peste, ils pariaient en somme sur le
> hasard et le hasard n’est à personne.

Quelqu'un pourrait-il expliquer ce que signifie « le hasard n'est à personne » dans le contexte de la phrase ci-dessus ? (Une explication rapide de la question—littéraire—de l'implication qui est faite par cette proposition pourrait être ajoutée à la réponse.)

On dit bien des choses comme par exemple « il avait la chance pour lui » et « la chance était avec eux », mais « la chance est à lui », en soi, ne signifie rien.

Answer (score 5):

Comme ils parient sur le hasard, ils pensent que le hasard va jouer en leur faveur, mais le hasard est le même pour tous, il ne *préfère* personne, personne ne maitrîse ou contrôle le hasard, personne ne le possède, il *n'est à personne*.

Comment: Si la formulation avait été « ils parient sur le hasard (prennent une chance avec le hasard) **parce que** le hasard n'est à personne (ne favorise personne) », ça serait clair, mais il s'agit d'un simple « et ».  Cette conjonction aurait le sens de « parce que » ?

Comment: @LPH Au contraire, la logique se montrait plus clairement s'il avait écrit *mais* : ils pariaient sur le hasard, *mais* il ne favorise personne, même ceux qui y font confiance. Ou bien : *et pourtant* il ne favorise personne. C'est que *et* peut exprimer une relation neutre, voire la simple conjonction de deux faits, où on peut lire *mais* ou *en conséquence* ou une autre relation. (Ceci n'est pas particulier au français : "I fought the law and the law won." Ou même en hébreu ancien où la traduction du mot *w-* (-ו‎) peut être ou *et* ou *mais*.)

Comment: Or it might be even clearer to see this *et* as joining two premises in a way that implies the *ergo*. Why did the *lutte* make them more vulnerable to the plague? Because (a) they wagered on it and (b) it doesn't favour gamblers.

Comment: @LukeSawczak In your opinion, then, there is no meaning that can clearly be insisted upon as certain;  the result of reading the sentence would only be a very vague idea.

Comment: Non, c'est très clair, il n'y a aucun problème avec ce _et_: deux faits sont présentés côte à côte, comme les deux prémisses d'une déduction, qui est elle-même laissée au lecteur. Exactement comme dit Luke.

Comment: @LPH Not so; I might not have expressed myself clearly. I meant that *et* is naturally polyvalent, but not that the sense intended in this case can't be resolved.

Comment: @LPH "ils parient sur le hasard parce que le hasard n'est à personne" n'est pas logique, à mon avis. S'il _n'est à personne_, pourquoi s'y fier? S'ils parient, c'est bien parce qu'ils pensent qu'ils seront sains et saufs même sans précaution sanitaire. L'explication correcte est simplement la juxtaposition de deux prémisses.

Comment: @Frank Selon cette façon de penser on s'y fierait parce que l'on serait sûr de l'impartialité, aucun humain ne pourrait le manipuler injustement contre nous ; mais cette façon de penser n'est pas nécessairement celle que sous-entend cette phrase, et j'ai des difficultés à traduire « et » par « parce que » (je ne trouve ça nulle part, ne le connais pas).

Answer (score 3):

Pour compléter la réponse de Frank d'un point de vue logique :

On peut le reformuler en une proposition de type "A et B impliquent C".

> A. Ils pariaient sur le hasard.
>
> B. Le hasard n'est à personne (*).
>
> C. => là était le vrai danger [ ... *tout ce qui est dit avant et se voit repris et renforcé par cet argument*  ]

(*) sous-entendu, il est son propre maître et bien fous sont ceux qui le négligent en pensant qu'il tournera toujours en leur faveur.